# sorting the sed output gives different results on Solaris 10 and 11

Tags: regex, sed, solaris

I have a command that extracts date from file names and counts the unique days:

`find xml/ -type f -name "*.201604*.xml" | head -5 | sed "s/.*\.\(2016[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | sort | uniq -c`

The results on Solaris 10 are:

```
# find xml/ -type f -name "*.201604*.xml" | head -5 | sed "s/.*\.\(2016[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | sort | uniq -c
   2 20160412
   1 20160417
   2 20160418
# uname -a
SunOS localhost 5.10 Generic_150400-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
# which sed sort
/usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/sort
```

The results on Solaris 11 are:

```
$ find xml/ -type f -name "*.201604*.xml" | head -5 | sed "s/.*\.\(2016[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | sort | uniq -c
   1 20160401
   1 20160403
   1 20160405
   1 xml/results/subres/ABC.DEF.GH01.20160401224003.123456.123456.xml
   1 xml/results/subres/ABC.DEF.GH02.20160412124035.234567.234567.xml
$ uname -a
SunOS localhost 5.11 11.2 sun4v sparc sun4v
$ which sed sort
/usr/bin/sed
/usr/bin/sort
```

For some reason, on Solaris 11 the `sort` command causes the `sed` to return full file path, instead of matched regex expression.

It works without sort though (Solaris 11):

```
$ find xml/ -type f -name "*.201604*.xml" | head -5 | sed "s/.*\.\(2016[0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1/g"
20160403
20160401
20160401
20160412
20160405
```

Why? Anyone else has this behaviour?

Comment: What output do you get on Solaris 11 if you replace `sort | uniq -c` with a simple `cat`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle same result as with `sort`, it shows two file names instead regex result.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a root prompt on the Solaris 10 server, which means you're likely running Solaris `sh` - and unlike Linux, Solaris has not conflated `sh` and `bash`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, no, the `sed` is not aliased. Also, the root prompt is fake, it's set by PS1="# ". `echo $SHELL` gives me `/usr/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by doing `unset LANG`. It was set to `en_US.UTF-8`. The `man` indicates that `LANG` affects `sed` command execution.

Comment: Why would piping the sed output to sort or not make any difference to that?

Answer (score 1):

`find` gives unsorted results. Sort the output of `find` before you use `head -5`.
Also `set LC_ALL=C`

Comment: I am aware of `find` unsorted results. In this case it doesn't make sense to do `sort` after `find`, since files have different naming conventions, and they won't be sorted by date. That is why I need to extract the date with regex.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `sort` AFTER you call `sed` so `sort` cannot affect how `sed` behaves. You're just picking up different versions of sed on each machine, probably one from /bin which doesn't understand the escaped ERE characters to create an RE interval (`\{4\}`) and the other from /usr/xpg4/bin or similar which does.

The case where you say Solaris 11 behaves differently with/without sort cannot happen without some environment change - maybe you're in a different shell or ran a different setup script or something.

Do `where sed` on both machines (or `which sed` or `whence sed` or...)

Comment: Please notice in the code examples, that I've already did `which sed sort`. The paths are the same.

Comment: Also, without a `sort` after `sed`, the results are correct, so it looks like `sort`, or `cat` affects the `sed`. Weird, since these are pipes.

Comment: And, only two of five output rows are not regex match results. So, it matches first three, and doesn't match two.

Comment: Ah, if you'd shown us the input to sed instead of just the output we'd have noticed that. Can't believe no-one, including me, thought to tell you to post that.